# Understanding "globalValidator" in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have custom validator and I register it in my controller

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new FooValidator());
    }

    @RequestMapping("/foo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void processFoo(@Valid Foo foo) { ... }

}
```

but I want to register in other controllers also,so to be able just to write @Valid and the Foo object to be validated. From what I see I understand that I can use @ControllerAdviced class which to register the validator on every controller, or to use

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven validator="globalValidator"/>
```

But how to register my validator, how Spring understand which Validator I want to make global one? Scans for every implementing **Validator** class? Can I do it with xml configuration? How to use this approach?

I do not understand the Spring's description:

> The alternative is to call setValidator(Validator) on the global
>   WebBindingInitializer. This approach allows you to configure a
>   Validator instance across all annotated controllers. This can be
>   achieved by using the SpringMVC namespace:
>
> xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
>       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>       xsi:schemaLocation="
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xss
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="globalValidator"/>
```

Comment: The validator named `globalValidator` ... Or the one named `fooBar` if you write `<mvc:annotation-driven validator="fooBar"/>`

Comment: So the "globalValidator" is just name of a previouslly created validator? So what if Iwan to put two of them to bi global?

Comment: You cannot.. You can only have a single global validator...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is quite clear on the [Validation section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-validation):

> In Spring MVC you can configure it for use **as a global Validator**
>   instance, to be used **whenever an @Valid or @Validated** controller
>   method argument **is encountered**, **and/or** as a **local Validator** within a
>   controller through **an @InitBinder method**. Global and local validator
>   instances **can be combined** to provide composite validation

If I understand correctly in your example the FooValidator you want to use it upon every validation as global Validator so define it as a bean and inject it as you show directly in the `mvc:annotation-driven` XML entry as you are showing already.

On top of that per-Controller you can have custom (applied on top only on that Controller-responsible forms) via the `@InitBinder` annotation.

As a side note, in your `@RequestMapping` method receiving the POST request where your `@Valid` parameter is: You can have a `BindingResult` entry right after that to take decisions on routes etc. In your example:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processFoo(@Valid Foo foo, BindingResult result) {

   if(result.hasErrors()) {
      return "go/that/way";
   }
   //..
}
```